# Determining of a family of functions is a normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix a $c>0$ and $\lambda \geq 0$.  Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of functions such that each $f$ satisfies the following three properties: analytic on the unit disk centred at the origin, $f(0)=0$, and $|f'(z)|\leq c(1-|z|)^{-\lambda}$ for all $z$ in the unit disk centered at the origin.

By Arzela-Ascoli, it is good enough to show that $\mathscr{F}$ is both equicontinuous and pointwise bounded.

Let $\epsilon >0$.  Then there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(z)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ provided that $|z-0|<\delta$ for $f \in \mathscr{F}$.   This shows equicontinuity.  I'm not sure how to show pointwise bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(z) = \int_C f'(w)\; dw$ where $C$ starts at $0$ and ends at $z$.
BTW you only asserted (and didn't prove) equicontinuity at $0$, not everywhere in the disk.

Comment: Would this be something like $f(z)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{z}f(w)\,dw$.  So $f'(z)=f(z)$ and $|f(z)|=|f'(z)|\leq c|1-|z||^{-\lambda}$.  I'm still not sure how to sure equicontinuity.

Comment: You don't generally use the notation $\int_0^z $ in complex analysis because integrals can depend on path, not just endpoints.  No, $f'$ is not the same as $f$.
For equicontinuity, you can again write $f(z_1) - f(z_2)$ as an integral of $f'$...

Comment: I see, so $|f(z)|\leq c(1-|z|)^{-\lambda}z$ by your hint. This shows pointwise bounder yes?